# Cleanup Android repo

Tags: android, git, android-source

A long time ago, I followed this guide: https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html
to download the master copy of Android Source Code. That was ~5GB as far as I remember.

Today I wanted to update my local copy to branch Android 4.4.4, so I followed the same guide but instead of requesting the master, I specified a branch using the `-b` command.

I noticed that the size of the final source code increased dramatically to ~12GB which leaves me suspicious that old unneeded files are not deleted using the `repo sync` command.

How can I clean up?

The output folder is not counted so those 12GB are pure source code only.

Comment: Android has increased in size a lot in recent years so what you're seeing is most likely in order. Unless you do a shallow clone, Git keeps all history so except when gits are removed from the manifest the size will always increase over time.

Comment: 12GB is perfectly normal.

Comment: If you used repo it cleans up folders that are not in projects and are also not repositories, and projects get updated to the specified branch, so you should be fine. As other commenters said, Android is big and this sounds normal.

Answer (score 3):

AOSP has increased in size a lot, so this size is perfectly normal. However, you can remove all files which is started with tmp_pack.

Go inside of source folder, then insert this command:

> find -name tmp_pack_* -delete

It can delete files which is downloaded partially.